# Convert Ubuntu server proxmox vm based on cloud image to desktop machine

Tags: cloud

I have a proxmox hypervisor where I have a vm whose disk is based on https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img

> qm disk import *vm-id* jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img vm-storage

Now, If I install ubuntu-desktop-minimal and then reboot, desktop doesn'start and remains stuck. If I do the same on a vm not based on cloud image, so just installed with ubuntu server lts iso, desktop works perfectly. It seems I'm missing some configuration and/or some extra packages to install. What are am doing wrong?